# How can I solve the error: Unable to write to User Settings because editor.parameterHints is not a registered configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is my problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R95uZ.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

had the same issue and the solution is that editor.parameterHints is now set with ".cycle" and ".enabled", meaning you need to update that setting in settings.json:

from

"editor.parameterHints": true,

to

"editor.parameterHints.enabled": true,

Here's the official documentation - just search the page for "parameterHints" to see relevant sections.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: Thanks. I know what the problem is now.